# How to create Youtube Live Event with all options

Tags: youtube

I wrote a .NET program that creates live events in Youtube, but I cannot set the correct starting time and some settings like Keywords, and Region.  This is what I do, when I create the Broadcast I put the starting Date and Time this way:

```
oLiveBroadcast.Snippet.ScheduledStartTime = String.Format(CDate(txtScheduledStart.Text), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzz")
```

...but the GMT is always referred to US (GMT -8). I think that the problem is in the receiving field .Snippet.ScheduledStartTime which has a dateTime format not including GMT. What can I do?

I also didn't find how and whare to set Region (in my case Itali IT-it) and searching Keywords

Thanks